# A little problem with AI. Pong Clone in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, pong

i 've a little problem making AI in Pong Clone, C# Unity. First paddle is controlled by the player and the second one by AI. I have following script for AI:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AI : MonoBehaviour
 {
   private Rigidbody2D AIrig;
   private GameObject ball;
public float speed = 100;
public float LerpSpeed = 1f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   AIrig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}



// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    ball = GameObject.Find("Ball(Clone)");

    if (ball.transform.position.y > transform.position.y)
    {
        if (ball.transform.position.y < 0)
        {
           
            AIrig.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(AIrig.velocity, Vector2.down * speed, LerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        else
        {
           
            AIrig.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(AIrig.velocity, Vector2.up * speed, LerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    
    if (ball.transform.position.y < transform.position.y && ball.transform.position.x > 1f)
    {
        if (ball.transform.position.y > 0)
        {
           
            AIrig.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(AIrig.velocity, Vector2.up * speed, LerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            
            AIrig.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(AIrig.velocity, Vector2.down * speed, LerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        
    }
    
    
   
}
```

And i don't know how to make it that AI's paddle back to it's original position. Anyone? Any suggestions? I will be very grateful for any advice from you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't find your ball in your fixedupdate method because it is expensive and you don't need. Instead just find it at start, so basically move that line to your start function.

If you mean original position as starting position just hold that position as vector3 or just a float and when you want your AI to move it's original position, just make it go to that position either with your same logic which is compairing it's position or any other way.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AI : MonoBehaviour
 {
   private Vector3 _originalPosition;// original position for the AI
   private Rigidbody2D AIrig;
   private GameObject ball;
   public float speed = 100;
   public float LerpSpeed = 1f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   ball = GameObject.Find("Ball(Clone)"); // finding the ball only 1 time
   AIrig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
   _originalPosition = AIrig.transform.position; // getting AI's original position
}



// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    

    if (ball.transform.position.y > transform.position.y)
    {
        if (ball.transform.position.y < 0)
        {
           
            AIrig.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(AIrig.velocity, Vector2.down * speed, LerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        else
        {
           
            AIrig.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(AIrig.velocity, Vector2.up * speed, LerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    
    if (ball.transform.position.y < transform.position.y && ball.transform.position.x > 1f)
    {
        if (ball.transform.position.y > 0)
        {
           
            AIrig.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(AIrig.velocity, Vector2.up * speed, LerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            
            AIrig.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(AIrig.velocity, Vector2.down * speed, LerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        
    }

    if(canGoToOriginalPosition)// the moment when you want it to go it's original position
    {
        //here you can just do the same logic and lerp it by comparing it's position or any other way.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply. Now when i've done this like you advised, AI Paddle still can't get back to position (it frezzes on the vertical edge of the screen). The second thing is that when i replaced find ball line to start method i've an error "MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
AI.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/AI.cs:28)". It its probably that ball is destroyed when one of the players gets a point and there is instantinated new.

Comment: Yes you should re find your ball when it is destroyed and instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for everything, You were very helpful! ;)

Comment: If i helped can you please give my answer a score :)